# Order discounting

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I am using the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module. On the checkout page, I need to add 'Subtotal' and 'Discount' fields above the 'Order total'.

The discount will be calculated by iterating through all products in the cart and (using some unique and complex PHP business logic that I won't get into here) calculating how much discount each product is eligible for.

The discount total will then be displayed in a 'Discount' field between 'Subtotal' and 'Total'.  The product prices should not be discounted.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you look on the discount modules? to check if they cant help you?

Comment: Thank you for the pointer Vic.  I take it you are referring to http://www.drupalcommerce.org/extensions/module/discount modules.  The Coupon modules might be useful as code references.

Answer (score 0):

So you will have to use the Rules modules with this

I guess its would something like : Calculating the sale price of products. Data comparision conditions should be added to this, then multiply the unit price by a certain amount, This would remove some % of the individual products which would give you the feature of removing it from the total amount.

Hope this help you

[Commerce Conditions](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_conditions)

[This link, might also give you closer indicator of how to solve the problem](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/4113/discount-amount-cart-does-not-work-properly)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Commerce Price Savings Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_savings_formatter) module.

Comment: Please add some details about WHY you recommend this module, and what this module does (eg via a relevant quote from its project page). Not doing so will put your answer at risk of being considered as a link-only answer (and possibly deleted via moderation). Just trying to help to improve your answer, ok?